# Android SQLite Get size of a table in kb

Tags: android, sqlite

I created an SQLite DB with two tables, day and data. The first table contains the date of each day with an id, the second table stores the corresponding data for each day with the id of the date.

Is it possible to get the size of the table data in kb or perhaps only of the data per day?

Comment: Went something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the size of the table data in kb or perhaps only of the data per day?

Kb per table Not easily, if at all.

- A table is comprised of pages (default 4K). A page may hold 0-many rows. You can easily obtain the size of the entire database but this will not indicate the number of pages that each table uses.

You could gather some approximation of the size of the data stored by utilising the [length()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) function.

For **example** (note a very simple example in regards to lengths as this would depend upon the character encoding e.g. in UTF-8 a character can take up 1-4 bytes) consdier the following based upon your description (2 tables **day** and **data**)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS day;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS day (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dateofdata_reference INTEGER REFERENCES day(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, datacolumn1 TEXT, datacolumn2 TEXT);

/* Add 3 days */
INSERT INTO day (date) VALUES('2019-01-01'),('2019-01-02'),('2019-01-03');
/* Add some data to each day assuming id of a day as 1,2 and then 3 for the 3 days */
INSERT INTO data (dateofdata_reference, datacolumn1,datacolumn2) VALUES
    (1,'A','XYZ'),(1,'ABC','UVW'),(1,'ABCD','RST') /* day 1 */
    ,(2,'Z','ZYX'),(2,'Y','WVU'),(2,'ZZ','TSR'),(2,'YYY','QPO') /* day 2 */
    ,(3,'J','1234567890') /* day 3 */
;

/* Combined length of data for entire table (excludes 1 and dateofdata_reference) */ 
SELECT sum(length(datacolumn1)) + sum(length(datacolumn2))  AS size FROM data;

/* Combined length of data and other stats per day (excludes id and dateofdata_reference) */ 
SELECT 
    date,
    sum(length(datacolumn1)) + sum(length(datacolumn2)) AS size,
    count() AS rowsPerDay,
    avg(length(datacolumn1) + length(datacolumn2)) AS averageRowSize,
    avg(length(datacolumn1)) AS averageDataColumn1Size,
    avg(length(datacolumn2)) AS averageDataColumn2Size

FROM data AS a
    JOIN day ON dateofdata_reference = day.id 
GROUP BY dateofdata_reference;


/* Cleanup demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS day;
```

The first (approx table size) query results in :-

[image]

The second (stats per day) results in :-
[image]

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for your detail response. I decided to show the size of the hole db with the following code: long size = new File(db.getPath()).length(); Best regards from Germany